# Copy Paste default Menu not coming in Text field & Textarea

Tags: android, iphone, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch based mobile site and app. I am not getting android/iphone default context menu of copy / pasting when i tap on it for long time.

Please suggest how can we do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can use this on TextView:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Comment: where should i use it?? IN the config of textarea/textfield ??

Comment: Look at here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_textIsSelectable ... And here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html